Use Angular as client (frontend) and Flask server as backend
I need to create a system that consists of:

Client - Angular application
Server - Flask server as backend that uses some python scripts form a local system

I don't really know how to make the client request things from the server. I have tried things like this:
In the Flask app.py:
@app.route('/getconcepts', methods=['GET'])
  def get_concepts():
    [...]
    return jsonify(concepts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)

Then, in the Angular client:
export class LeftNavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  archiveLinkList: Archivelink[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http.get<string[]>('http://localhost:5000/getconcepts').subscribe(
      (concepts: string[]) => {

        this.archiveLinkList = conceptos.map((concept, index) => ({
          // Archivelink parameters
          id: index,
          concept: encodeURIComponent(concept),
          url: `/display?concept=${encodeURIComponent(concepto)}`
        }));
      },

      error => {
        console.error('Error fetching concepts:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}

The Angular client can be accessed at localhost:4200
It does not work and I can't find anything that fixes my problem.

I'm back and I solved it. Figured I might provide an answer for this in case someone encounters the same problem.

It took me an embarrassing amount of time, to be honest, but I was surfing from one deprecated explanation to another.
Ok, first of all, https://angular.io/guide/build (section 'Proxying to a backend') approach is deprecated, specifically step 3: adding the following code to angular.json.
"options": {
    "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
}

Now, I was previously following this tutorial: Build your first Angular app
I didn't finished because I figured (WRONG) I didn't need some of the ending steps for my project. Well, I did.
This is the way I solved everything, there might be another approach but this is what ended up working for me:
Creating a service in the angular app.

Angular services provide a way for you to separate Angular app data
and functions that can be used by multiple components in your app.

This is optional, but I did it anyway just so I learnt how to.

Use an injectable.


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';: Imports the Injectable
function from Angular, which is used to mark the class as a service
that can be injected into other classes.


Add the HTTP communication, following this step of the tutorial

This is how you can connect to the data, the data must be published in a route, mine is localhost:5000/getconcepts
So, this is the service I created to test it:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Archivelink } from './archivelink'; // my data class

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() { }
  url = 'http://localhost:5000/getconcepts';
  async getAllArchiveLink(): Promise<Archivelink[]> { // uses asynchronous code to make a GET request
    const data = await fetch(this.url);
    return await data.json() ?? [];
  }
}


We use the service in the component we desire
import {MyService} from '../myservice.service';
export class LeftNavigationComponent{
archiveLinkList: Archivelink[] = [];
myService: MyService = inject(MyService);
constructor() {
this.myService.getAllArchiveLink().then((archiveLinkList: Archivelink[]) => {
this.archiveLinkList = archiveLinkList;
});
}
}

Modify the app.py file so everything works properly


An error I encountered was that I did the GET request but the data was not shown. While review the log in the navigator terminal, I found out it was a CORS error.
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask("api test", static_url_path='/static')
CORS(app) # VERY IMPORTANT
@app.route('/getconcepts', methods=['GET'])
def get_concepts():    
    [... get the concepts (in my code, as a json file) ...]
    return concepts
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)

And that's it, it works fine for me, luckily.
Hope this helps somebody! Have a great day (night for me jeje) :D
